# FunctionPeriod returns 0 if input trigonometric function have a real phase

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-function

I am using Mathematica 10, `FunctionPeriod` which is supposed to return period of a given function returns 0 if the input trigonometric function have a Real phase

```
In[1]:= FunctionPeriod[Cos[t+1.2], t]
Out[1]= 0
In[2]:= FunctionPeriod[Cos[t+1], t]
Out[2]= 2 π
In[3]:= FunctionPeriod[Cos[t+1.0], t]
Out[3]= 0
```

Why the period is zero if the phase is a real number instead of `2 π` and why `Cos[t+1]` and `Cos[t+1.0]` are not having the same period

Comment: I suppose the reason is related to the result of `Cos[t+1.2+2 Pi] == Cos[t+1.2]`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @QuantumDot I'd guess that the implicit question is either "how do I get the expected behavior" i.e. a result of `2 Pi` or "why am I not getting the expected behavior".

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Thanks for the clarification; Neel should edit his post to explicitly state the question.

Comment: question edited

Comment: See what happens when you evaluate `Cos[1.] - Cos[1. + 2 Pi]`.

Comment: Yeah, I think @JohnDoty has the right of it. Further evidence: `FunctionPeriod[Rationalize@Cos[t + 1.2], t]` yields `2 π`.